# This Is Definitely Not Me!

Tags: riddle, word

More Riley Riddles :D

> My prefix you will love
>
> After adding a letter to it
>
> My infix can be a little devil
>
> Just don't come near it
>
> My suffix is a homophone
>
> Of something quite round

Note :

> Title is a hint

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer

Infix

> maybe an IMP referring to little devil

Suffix

> BALL from BALL and BAWL and a ball is quite round

Comment: One of your answers is on the right track :D

Answer (score 1):

Is this

> SIMPLE or SIMPSON?

My prefix you will love 
After adding a letter to it

> SI + S = SIS, someone whom you will love.

My infix can be a little devil 
Just don't come near it

> IMP, as mentioned above.

My suffix is a homophone 
Of something quite round

> The SUN is quite round, SON is a homophone. Otherwise you can PULL something a-round (a PEARL is also round), PLE is a homophone-ish.

Altogether, you’re definitely not

> Either SIMPLE or a SIMPSON.

Comment: Unfortunately incorrect :)